# Creating a command similar to \vrule

Tags: macros, framed

Upon trying to create a new border similar to the `\vrule` command, I have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,framed,lipsum}

\def\bulletfill{\vbox to 3ex{\vfil\hbox{$\bullet$}\vfil}}

\newenvironment{defn}[1][blue]{%
\def\FrameCommand##1{
{\color{#1}\vbox to \ht0{\xleaders\bulletfill\vfill}}%
\setbox0=\hbox{%
\colorbox{yellow!20}{%
##1
}%
}%
\usebox0}%
\MakeFramed {\advance\hsize -\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\begin{document}
\begin{defn}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{defn}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the `\bullet` is not being copied but if change `\vbox to \ht0` to say `\vbox to \vsize` the bullets appear. Weird? The question is then, why is it behaving in such a manner and a possible solution to the copying of the bullet as a border.

Answer (score 6):

Here a solution using `mdframed`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}


\newmdenv[hidealllines=true,leftline=true,
                   linecolor=yellow!20,backgroundcolor=yellow!20,
                   tikzsetting={draw=blue,dashed,dash pattern= on 1pt off 3pt}]{defn}

\begin{document}
\begin{defn}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{defn}
\end{document}
```

Comment: using your own packages is cheating:)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I know ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. By defining the box content first allows for the existence of `\ht0` for the use in the `\vbox`.

```
\newenvironment{defn}[1][blue]{%
\def\FrameCommand##1{%
\setbox0=\hbox{%
\colorbox{yellow!20}{%
##1
}%
}%
{\color{#1}\vbox to \ht0{\xleaders\bulletfill\vfill}}%
\usebox0}%
\MakeFramed {\advance\hsize -\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}
```

added note from David:

A more orthodox set of LaTeX box commands would be

```
\newenvironment{defn}[1][blue]{%
\def\FrameCommand##1{%
\sbox{0}{\colorbox{yellow!20}{##1}%
}%
\parbox[b][\ht0]{0pt}{\color{#1}\xleaders\bulletfill\vfill}%
\usebox{0}}%
\MakeFramed {\advance\hsize -\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}
```

Comment: you are missing a `%` after `##1` you also have a strange mixture of latex and primitives, `\usebox` not `\box`  or for latex `\setbox` not `\savebox` although it works beware primitive box saving commands are not colour safe

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So what should be used? I would appreciate the correction as an edit.